# wp-cli displays php notices when display errors off

Tags: command-line, wp-cli

I am using wp-cli and I am having php notices and errors show up when running wp-export. Some of these warnings and errors are ending up in the output file. How can I force errors to NOT show up. I have tried `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` and `error_reporting(0);` in wp-wp-config.php

```
root@roc-apache-4:/var/www/blogs/html# wp export --quiet=true --debug=false --url=http://blogs.democratandchronicle.com/fleet-feet-beat/ --dir=/root/wordpress_exports --file_item_count=100000000
PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'America/New York' is invalid in phar:///usr/bin/wp/php/wp-cli.php(21) : eval()'d code on line 16
PHP Notice:  Constant ABSPATH already defined in phar:///usr/bin/wp/php/wp-cli.php(21) : eval()'d code on line 68
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: combineCommentCounts in /var/www/blogs/html/wp-content/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/facebook-comments.php on line 265

Notice: Undefined index: combineCommentCounts in /var/www/blogs/html/wp-content/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/facebook-comments.php on line 265
PHP Notice:  define() was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 3.0! The constant <code>VHOST</code> <strong>is deprecated</strong>. Use the boolean constant <code>SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL</code> in wp-config.php to enable a subdomain configuration. Use is_subdomain_install() to check whether a subdomain configuration is enabled. in /var/www/blogs/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3466
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to do your PHP error settings in your `php.ini` file unless [the PHP ini directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) don't list it as `PHP_INI_ALL` - which is the case for nearly error related definition.

So I'm assuming you just misread something and set stuff to `wp_settings.php` instead of `wp-config.php`.

The next point is that WP CLI *might* run WP in different cases without some stuff loaded, so it could get bypassed.

The safest point to set some `php.ini` stuff always is your php.ini file. And if you can't work around errors: Go and fix them - that's what errors, warnings and notices are for. If it's a plugin causing it, send a pull request and notify the author.

---

Note: If you are in/on your Terminal/Command Line, you can use `php --ini` to list all locations where your `php.ini` files are stored. Some operating systems support different locations per default. And some packages like XDebug have additional locations per default.

Example `php --ini` result on Windows:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\dev\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Example `php --ini` result on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
```

Comment: I have tried `php.ini` for cli and apache2 and display_errors is Off. I did try adding `error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to wp-config.php. I don't have the time to e-mail plugin owners. I just need errors to NOT show up.

Comment: It appears the problem was due to log_errors = On. In CLI mode it was logging errors to screen

Comment: Nice, that you found a solution. But honestly: You don't have time to mail authors? Come on. You're using software for free but ain't got time for error reports while you got time to dig in it, play around with it, ask questions about it and then comment on it? Again: Come on. This is the minimum an author could expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--require=` argument to include a file that sets error reporting level and whether or not to display errors. I did something similar to this in a shell script:

```
# Suppress errors by including this generated file
echo "<?php error_reporting(0); @ini_set('display_errors', 0);" > __pre.php

rc=0

for i in 905 1000 10001; do
    wp --quiet --no-color --user=admin --require=./__pre.php \
        post update $i --post_status=draft \
           || (rc=1 && break)
done

rm -f __pre.php
exit $rc
```

Note the `./` because it will not default to the local path but will use PHP's `include_path`. Need to bypass that in this case.

If you do not suppress the errors, *any* PHP notice will cause an exit status of non-zero. Not desirable in my case because I want the loop to stop as soon as any *real* error occurs.

Comment: Using the --require option and adding those error_reporting functions doesn't seem to work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

My solution to disable notices etc is to know if the wp-config.php is call via cli or not. So put this little code in wp-config.php

```php
$sapi_type = php_sapi_name();
if ( $sapi_type == 'cli' ) {
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
} else {
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
}
```

Comment: Most excellent. Funnily enough, the cli shows a different set of warnings if debug is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely 2 php.ini files

- **`/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`** This is for your Command Line Interface (CLI)
- **`/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`** This is for your Web Server, in this case Apache2

To update what errors are reported on the command line, update the `error_reporting` line in the `cli/php.ini`

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```