# PHP warning are displaying when using WP CLI

Tags: wp-cli, warnings

I'm running WP CLI 0.25.0 on Debian, PHP 7.0. I keep getting the PHP warnings displayed. In php.ini used for cli I have set `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING` (and checked the change), but no difference, the warning is output.

Ran WP CLI with `--debug=false`, still no effect.

How to suppress the warning display, as it breaks the JSON output ?

**Edit 1**

Before using error_log = Off :

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/.../theme-settings.php on line 2805
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/.../theme-settings.php on line 2805

Using error_log = Off :

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/.../theme-settings.php on line 2805

Pay attention that the `PHP Warning` disapeared, and theres the `Warning` left.

Comment: In the "Related" list here in the right sidebar, we can find a similar question: [wp-cli displays php notices when display errors off](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100234/wp-cli-displays-php-notices-when-display-errors-off?rq=1) where the problem seems to be the log_error settings for the OP.

Comment: Does --quiet=true do what you need?

Comment: @birgire, yes, this was the problem. I have set `log_errors = Off` and it helped !

Comment: @ScottyJakes, the `--quiet=true` didn't help :(

Comment: @birgire, please add your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. What about closing this as a duplicate and you adding it as a solution to the linked question (describing what worked for you) ? @SpartakusMd

Comment: @birgire, ehm, it seems it didn't fully help as I still get warnings :(

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check for this issue is the WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_LOG and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY constants in the wp-config.php file. They have to be set to false or be commented out (the default value is false). Else, no matter which global log_errors, display_errors or error_reporting settings you have, you will still see those warnings when running wp-cli.